# How does Matlab decide to accept a step in fminunc?

Tags: matlab, minimization

I'm using fminunc. Specifically, I'm using a quasi-newton method with BFGS and a user supplied gradient to minimize a function. It goes for about 3 iterations, then does a bunch of function evaluations. I have the function I am trying to minimize display its value when it is called, and I can see that after a few calls on the 4th iteration it is significantly smaller than it was on the third iteration, but Matlab continues to evaluate the function and I'm not sure why. Is there something I can adjust to tell it to accept the update and move to the next iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you understand the optimizer pretty well, let's see if we can help with the optimset settings.  From the [mathworks docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html) it calls out how to relax the tolerances to terminate the optimization with the following parameters:

> TolFun    Termination tolerance on the function value, a positive scalar. The
>                 default is 1e-6.
>
> TolX          Termination tolerance on x, a positive scalar. The default value is
>                 1e-6.

Sounds like you have the Optimization Toolbox, in which case I believe you can use [optimset](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimset.html) to get the optimization parameters and then use the `fminunc` to initialize it.(The docs for the regular optimset don't call out that you can pass the `fminunc` as an argument, but I would think it would work for the toolbox version.

```
options = optimset('fminunc');
% you can try either of these two or both, but I would
% recommend only changing one at a time :-)
options = optimset(options,'TolFun',myNewTolFun)
options = optimset(options,'TolX',myNewTolX)
% then you can make your call to the optimizer
x = fminunc(fun,x0,options)
```

Excruciating detail on the optim-settings can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-options-reference.html).